# How to deploy Django without mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm relatively new to web development, but I have a couple years experience working with python, so I figured I would build my first production site using django.

I've spent the last few days learning the basics and building a test site running on my local machine. Today, I've been trying to deploy my site to production; however, I've hit a pretty large stumbling block.

The django documentation [suggests using mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for apache deployments. I followed the install instructions [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html), only to realize that I don't have access to make any changes to apache - I'm currently on a shared hosting plan.

Apparently, to perform the install, I would have to upgrade to a VPS plan, which costs a lot more.

Any advice for a new web developer trying to get a proof-of-concept web app together (preferably with feedback gathered from real users) on a budget?

I think I have two options:

1. Eat the cost on my current web hosting plan. Try to find a cheaper host that specializes in django hosting. I've been looking at the following (suggestions here would be wonderful):

   - Heroku
   - DigitalOcean
   - A2Hosting
2. Try some sort of manual deployment. Is this possible or has anybody ever made this work? I can't seem to find any resources about this.

   - I was able to install django on my web server and my site just seems like a collection of files at this point. Can I simply move this directory tree to my site using an ftp? And handle the database migration manually?
   - Can I just run django on my web server via ssh instead of from my local machine? Essentially just rebuild my site in production? I know this isn't a smart idea with a normal production site, but as a proof of concept, I don't mind some downtime if my code is buggy.

Thanks!

Comment: I find it very unlikely that even a shared hosting doesn't support wsgi. Can you share the name of the hosting company?

Comment: I use Webfaction, Google Cloud and Azure. Their cheapest stuff is good enough for proof-of-concept web apps and even for production.

Comment: I'm using InMotion Hosting right now. Saw that they don't support wsgi in [this support ticket](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/general-server-setup/have-pro-plan-need-one-domain-to-run-django-vps-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just starting [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) is probably perfect for you. It's super easy to set up, you don't have to handle the server configuration yourself and it has a free tier to do some tests until you are ready to go.

If you are OK with doing some more advanced server/service configuration, you can use Google Cloud, Azure or AWS. This last one has a [one year free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?nc1=h_ls). If you go this route, I suggest using gunicorn/uwsgi + nginx instead of Apache mod_wsgi.